# How to parse and create data frame from RIXML/XML in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xml

I am just starting with Python and we have a use case where we need to parse a xml type structure RIXML and save as tabular format or create JSON or create it as a csv file .
But for all of output we have to parse the xml .
I have been trying many ways but ElementTree is the one that we should be using to parse this kind of xml structure .
Please correct me if this assumption is wrong.
Here is my xml tree .
Sorry to post entire xml .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Research xmlns="http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML" language="eng" createDateTime="2022-03-25T12:18:11.527Z" researchID="123456">
   <Product sequence="0" eventIndicator="No" productID="7448811">
      <StatusInfo currentStatusIndicator="Yes" statusDateTime="2022-03-25T12:21:12.269Z" statusType="Published" />
      <Source>
         <Organization type="SellSideFirm" primaryIndicator="Yes">
            <OrganizationID idType="TrRefi">5219</OrganizationID>
            <OrganizationID idType="VendorCode">ABCD</OrganizationID>
            <OrganizationID idType="ONEAccess">497</OrganizationID>
            <OrganizationName nameType="Display">abcd Securities (Australia) Limited</OrganizationName>
            <PersonGroup>
               <PersonGroupMember primaryIndicator="Yes">
                  <Person personID="3881">
                     <FamilyName>Bairstow</FamilyName>
                     <GivenName>mATHEY</GivenName>
                     <DisplayName>mATHEY Bairstow</DisplayName>
                     <JobTitle>Division Director</JobTitle>
                     <ContactInfo nature="Business">
                        <Email>mATHEY.bairstow@abcd.com</Email>
                        <Phone type="Voice">
                           <CountryCode />
                           <Number>+61 165 123 321</Number>
                        </Phone>
                     </ContactInfo>
                  </Person>
               </PersonGroupMember>
               <PersonGroupMember primaryIndicator="No">
                  <Person personID="5554">
                     <FamilyName>Scholtz</FamilyName>
                     <GivenName>John</GivenName>
                     <DisplayName>John Scholtz</DisplayName>
                     <JobTitle>Research Analyst</JobTitle>
                     <ContactInfo nature="Business">
                        <Email>John.scholtz@abcd.com</Email>
                        <Phone type="Voice">
                           <CountryCode />
                           <Number>+61 100 036 200</Number>
                        </Phone>
                     </ContactInfo>
                  </Person>
               </PersonGroupMember>
               <PersonGroupMember primaryIndicator="No">
                  <Person personID="5116">
                     <FamilyName>Bowler</FamilyName>
                     <GivenName>Andrew</GivenName>
                     <DisplayName>Andrew Bowler</DisplayName>
                     <JobTitle>Research Analyst</JobTitle>
                     <ContactInfo nature="Business">
                        <Email>andrew.bowler@abcd.com</Email>
                        <Phone type="Voice">
                           <CountryCode />
                           <Number>+61 448 433 736</Number>
                        </Phone>
                     </ContactInfo>
                  </Person>
               </PersonGroupMember>
               <PersonGroupMember primaryIndicator="No">
                  <Person personID="6076">
                     <FamilyName>Yun</FamilyName>
                     <GivenName>Austin</GivenName>
                     <DisplayName>Austin Yun,  CFA</DisplayName>
                     <JobTitle>Senior Research Associate Analyst</JobTitle>
                     <ContactInfo nature="Business">
                        <Email>austin.yun@abcd.com</Email>
                        <Phone type="Voice">
                           <CountryCode />
                           <Number>+61 457 429 116</Number>
                        </Phone>
                     </ContactInfo>
                  </Person>
               </PersonGroupMember>
            </PersonGroup>
         </Organization>
      </Source>
      <Content>
         <Title>Australian Lithium and Rare Earths Miners</Title>
         <SubTitle>DLE under the spotlight</SubTitle>
         <Abstract>Key Lithium and Rare Earths market themes
.</Abstract>
         <Synopsis>Spodumene prices edged higher during the week while Chinese lithium carbonate prices remained flat. We review Direct Lithium Extraction method following POSCO’s .</Synopsis>
         <Resource primaryIndicator="Yes" resourceID="7448811">
            <MIMEType>application/pdf</MIMEType>
            <Name>ref.0007448811.20220325.pdf</Name>
            <URL>https://www.abcdresearch.com</URL>
         </Resource>
      </Content>
      <Context external="Yes">
         <IssuerDetails>
            <Issuer primaryIndicator="No" issuerType="Corporate">
               <SecurityDetails>
                  <Security primaryIndicator="No">
                     <SecurityID tradingCountryCode="KR" idValue="005490.KS" idType="RIC" />
                     <SecurityID tradingCountryCode="KR" idValue="005490 KS" idType="Bloomberg" />
                     <SecurityFinancials securityFinancialsType="Price">
                        <Currency>KRW</Currency>
                        <FinancialValue estimateActual="Actual">304000.00</FinancialValue>
                     </SecurityFinancials>
                     <SecurityFinancials securityFinancialsType="TargetPrice">
                        <Currency>KRW</Currency>
                        <FinancialValue dateTime="2022-03-25T12:18:14.215Z" estimateActual="Estimate">280000.00</FinancialValue>
                     </SecurityFinancials>
                     <SectorIndustry primaryIndicator="No" focusLevel="No" classificationType="GICS" level="4" code="15104050">
                        <ShortName>Steel</ShortName>
                        <Name>Steel (15104050)</Name>
                     </SectorIndustry>
                     <SecurityName>POSCO</SecurityName>
                     <SecurityShortName>POSCO</SecurityShortName>
                     <AssetClass assetClass="Equity" />
                     <AssetType assetType="Stock" />
                     <Rating rating="NeutralSentiment" priorCurrent="Current" timeFrame="ShortTerm">
                        <PublisherDefinedValue>NEUTRAL</PublisherDefinedValue>
                        <RatingEntity ratingEntity="Publisher" />
                     </Rating>
                  </Security>
               </SecurityDetails>
               <IssuerName nameType="Display">
                  <PublisherDefinedValue />
                  <NameValue>POSCO</NameValue>
               </IssuerName>
            </Issuer>
            <Issuer primaryIndicator="No" issuerType="Corporate">
               <SecurityDetails>
                  <Security primaryIndicator="No">
                     <SecurityID tradingCountryCode="CN" idValue="6445490" idType="SEDOL" />
                     <SectorIndustry primaryIndicator="No" focusLevel="No" classificationType="GICS" level="4" code="15101030">
                        <ShortName>Fertilizers &amp; Agricultural Chemicals</ShortName>
                        <Name>Fertilizers &amp; Agricultural Chemicals (15101030)</Name>
                     </SectorIndustry>
                     <SecurityName>ZANGGE MINING CO L</SecurityName>
                     <SecurityShortName>ZANGGE MINING CO L</SecurityShortName>
                     <AssetClass assetClass="Equity" />
                     <AssetType assetType="Stock" />
                     <Rating rating="NoRating" priorCurrent="Current" timeFrame="ShortTerm">
                        <PublisherDefinedValue />
                        <RatingEntity ratingEntity="Publisher" />
                     </Rating>
                  </Security>
               </SecurityDetails>
               <IssuerName nameType="Display">
                  <PublisherDefinedValue />
                  <NameValue>ZANGGE MINING CO L</NameValue>
               </IssuerName>
            </Issuer>
         </IssuerDetails>
         <ProductDetails publicationDateTime="2022-03-24T13:00:00.000Z">
            <ProductCategory publisherDefinedValue="Flyer" productCategory="PublisherDefined" />
            <ProductFocus primaryIndicator="Yes" focus="SectorIndustry" />
            <EntitlementGroup>
               <Entitlement includeExcludeIndicator="Include" primaryIndicator="Yes">
                  <AudienceTypeEntitlement entitlementContext="TrRefi" audienceType="PublisherDefined">1</AudienceTypeEntitlement>
               </Entitlement>
            </EntitlementGroup>
         </ProductDetails>
         <ProductClassifications>
            <Discipline researchApproach="Fundamental" disciplineType="Investment" />
            <Country primaryIndicator="Yes" code="AU" />
            <Region regionType="Australasia" primaryIndicator="Yes" />
            <AssetClass assetClass="Equity" />
            <SectorIndustry primaryIndicator="Yes" focusLevel="Yes" classificationType="GICS" level="3" code="151040">
               <ShortName>Metals &amp; Mining</ShortName>
               <Name>Metals &amp; Mining (151040)</Name>
            </SectorIndustry>
         </ProductClassifications>
      </Context>
   </Product>
</Research>
```

Is there anyway to parse this xml and all of its attribute ?

This is how i have started with

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree
import pandas as pd

# give the path where you saved the xml file
# inside the quotes
xmldata = "C:\\Users\\myxmlfile-rixml.xml"
prstree = ETree.parse(xmldata)
root = prstree.getroot()
print("root tag ----"+root.tag)
print(root.attrib)

for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

In the method how can we get StatusInfo  and Organization  tags and its elements

Comment: @mzjn i am not able to find StatusInfo  and Organization  tags and attributes

Comment: `for child in root` only finds immediate children of `root`. `StatusInfo` and `Organization` are not immediate children (they are deeper in the hierarchy). You could try `iter()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict)

And after that you can serialize the dict to a json or something else

Comment: Can you help in how can i get StatusInfo  and Organization tag value and its attribute